# c sharp -winform application with a listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview in C sharp windows forms application like in the following. The following code of lines are there in Form_load() method .

But the issue is it does not start inserting a row from first column. Instead , it starts from the second column. Because of that value passed to the last column is always lost.

```
        listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnOne", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnTwo", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnThree", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnFour", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnFive", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Column6", 150);

        foreach (MyClass et in _myData)
        {
            ListViewItem lt = new ListViewItem();

            lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataOne.ToString());

            lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataTwo.ToString());
            lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataThree.ToString());
            lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataFour.ToLongDateString());
            lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataFive);
            lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataSix);
        }
```

I tried everything possible. I don't even see that I have made a mistake. Can someone pls give me a solution to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ListView` is a bit clunky when it comes to the different columns. What is shown in the first column in `Detail` view is actually the text of the `ListViewItem` itself and not the first `SubItem`. So what you want to do is start assigning `DataTwo` and so on to the `subgroups` and `DataOne` to the `ListViewItem.Text`:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnOne", 150);
listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnTwo", 150);
listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnThree", 150);
listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnFour", 150);
listView1.Columns.Add("ColumnFive", 150);
listView1.Columns.Add("Column6", 150);

foreach (MyClass et in _myData)
{
    ListViewItem lt = new ListViewItem(et.DataOne.ToString());

    lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataTwo.ToString());
    lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataThree.ToString());
    lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataFour.ToLongDateString());
    lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataFive);
    lt.SubItems.Add(et.DataSix);

    // I added this to your code
    listView1.Items.Add(lt);
}
```